# Understanding John McAfee's note about a seemingly novel, yet simple, anomaly in the XOR operation?

Tags: cryptography, computer-science, linear-algebra, xor, boolean-algebra

John McAfee (the founder of McAfee anti virus company) has two tweets ([first](https://twitter.com/officialmcafee/status/1397568860082122752?cxt=HHwWgMC95afelOUmAAAA) and [second](https://twitter.com/officialmcafee/status/1397817824220004352)) in which he shares a seemingly novel note about an anomaly in XOR operation. I understand how XOR operation combines the information of two datasets, but I'm not quite sure if I understand what anomaly McAfee is exactly referring to. Can you please give an example of the anomaly that doesn't exist with 3 datasets, but exists with 6 datasets?

Here is McAfee's note:

> Boolean algebra is one of the foundations of computer science. There
> is an unusual property of the boolean XOR operation that I doubt many,
> or anyone at all, has considered:
>
> If you take any three sets of
> characters of any equal length - let's label them A, B and C - and
> then:
>
> XOR A to B
>
> Then XOR the result of B to C
>
> Then similarly XOR C to A
>
> And then perform four iterations of the above. And finally: XOR A to
> B And then B to C It will result in the original contents of A moved
> to C, C moved to B and B moved to A.
>
> Of interest here is that the
> three results of the third iteration, though deterministic as a whole,
> are entirely random within each of the three independent data
> segments. Thus if any one of the three segments is missing or
> withheld, it is impossible, from the remaining two to extract even the
> tiniest fragment of the three original contents.
>
> The simplicity of
> this process is astonishing. A person of average intelligence could
> decode a message, using pencil and paper, providing they possessed all
> three interim segments.
>
> I'm describing this tidbit in the hopes that
> my observations might be of some small use to those engaged in the
> research of cryptography.
>
> Addendum:
>
> The same concept of sequential XOR operations works with four data
> sets requiring three iterations and five data sets with two
> iterations.
>
> ** Strangely with six sets, the process unravels and produces chaos no
> matter how many iterations.**
>
> Please God, someone explain.

Comment: It's not completely clear what he's suggesting, but from what I can make of it there's nothing novel or anomalous here. Nor does this question seem like a programming question, so it's probably off-topic.

Comment: Nothing here seems particularly mysterious if you have spent any time working with XOR. John McAfee, despite his famous history, is now more known for being quite addled, perhaps as a schtick, perhaps due to extensive drug use. I would not assume that anything he says is coherent. If you want to gain a better understanding, I recommend an introductory course in cryptography. https://www.coursera.org/learn/crypto

Comment: It sure sounds like he's making the rather trivial observation that if I know the value of A^B, I still don't know anything at all about A or B, as they can have any value.  This is a rather boring result.  If I'm working in say 64 bits, and I know the value of A + B, I know nothing about A or B.  Or even A - B.  

Big nothingburger.